# Does this code read the first 10000 lines from a file?

Tags: python

```
def read_text(bz2_loc, n=10000):
    with BZ2File(bz2_loc) as file_:
        for i, line in enumerate(file_):
            data = json.loads(line)
            yield data["body"]
            if i >= n:
                break
```

I think it reads each line and return the result immediately, and when it reaches 10000 lines, it jumps out of the loop. This piece of code doesn't complete the reading of the whole file. Is that true?

If I want to read the whole file, and yield once for each 10000, how to modify it?

Comment: What did it do when you ran it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```py
def read_text(bz2_loc, n=10000):
    with BZ2File(bz2_loc) as file_:
        lines = []
        for i, line in enumerate(file_):
            data = json.loads(line)
            lines.append(data["body"])
            if i % n == 0:
                yield lines
                lines = []
```

Just be aware that this will also yield the very first line if `i` starts at `0`

Comment: this deosn't return 10000 for each batch.

Comment: @FabZanna note that `enumerate` gives 0 as the first index value...

Comment: @Ed Ward I know. I pointed it out